# SQL Server databases not accessed for 1 month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I'm trying to cleanup some servers and want to find out which databases have not been accessed in the last 30 days. How can I change my T-SQL query to where only databases that have not been accessed in the last 30 days appear?

For additional info, I also include when the server was last rebooted. This is not really relevant for this question.

For example, today is October 10th. Any database that has been accessed since September 10th, I do not want to appear in my query results.

Here is my current T-SQL script to find out the last time the database were accessed on my server:

```
SELECT
    DB_NAME(sd.database_id) AS DatabaseName,
    COALESCE(MAX(ius.last_user_seek), MAX(ius.last_user_scan),
             MAX(ius.last_user_lookup), MAX(ius.last_user_update), '1/1/1900') AS LastAccessDate,
    (SELECT create_date 
     FROM sys.databases 
     WHERE name = 'tempdb') AS LastServerRestart
FROM 
    sys.databases sd
LEFT JOIN
    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats ius ON ius.database_id = sd.database_id
WHERE 
    DB_NAME(sd.database_id) NOT IN ('tempdb', 'master', 'model', 'msdb')
GROUP BY 
    sd.database_id
ORDER BY 
    DatabaseName
```

These are the results of this query:

```
DatabaseName            LastAccessDate             LastServerRestart
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
AdventureWorks2016      2018-09-12 18:21:21.800    2018-09-12 18:21:10.727
AdventureWorksDW2016    2018-10-10 09:40:31.903    2018-09-12 18:21:10.727
Drake_Test              1900-01-01 00:00:00.000    2018-09-12 18:21:10.727
OLD_DB                  1900-01-01 00:00:00.000    2018-09-12 18:21:10.727
Drake_Test_new          2018-10-10 14:20:17.943    2018-09-12 18:21:10.727
```

Based on these results, I would only want `Drake_Test` and `OLD_DB` to be returned from that query. The other 3 databases have been accessed in the past 30 days.

Also, a main problem with changing my T-SQL query is that when I try to use the `LastAccessDate` column as part of a clause, it says that it's an invalid column?

Comment: Look up the HAVING clause.

Comment: When I try to use the LastAccessDate column as part of a clause, it says that it's an invalid column.

Comment: You will need to use the full statement defining the column.

Comment: @drake "HAVING" actually does work. If you have a query that uses it but throws an error, please update your question to show the actual query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like using CTEs for this kind of thing:

```
WITH CTE AS (
     SELECT DB_NAME(sd.database_id) AS DatabaseName,
            COALESCE(
               MAX(ius.last_user_seek),
               MAX(ius.last_user_scan),
               MAX(ius.last_user_lookup),
               MAX(ius.last_user_update),
               '1/1/1900') AS LastAccessDate,
               (SELECT create_date FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'tempdb') AS LastServerRestart
     FROM sys.databases sd
     LEFT JOIN sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats ius on ius.database_id = sd.database_id
     WHERE DB_NAME(sd.database_id) NOT IN('tempdb', 'master', 'model', 'msdb')
     GROUP BY sd.database_id)

SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE LastAccessDate < DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())
ORDER BY DatabaseName
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Only change I made was WHERE LastAccessDate < DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE()). Since I only want the databases that haven't been used in last 30 days.

Comment: @drake Good call, fixed that sign.  And yeah, CTEs are nice because you don't have to repeat a bunch of logic and can instead reference a column name/alias directly.  Happy to help.